# C: Compiler info at runtime

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Is there a way to print the name of the compiler and the version that was used to compile a program, something like;

```
printf("This is compiled with %s version %s\n", COMPILER, COMPILER_VERSION);
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with the pre-processor:

Reference: http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html

For gcc:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
# if defined(__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
#  define __GNUC_VERSION__ (__GNUC__ * 10000 \
                            + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 \
                            + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
# else
#  define __GNUC_VERSION__ (__GNUC__ * 10000 \
                            + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100)
# endif
#endif
```

For MSVC just use:

```
_MSC_FULL_VER
```

Comment: Err...  What if I used microsoft's compilers?

Comment: _MSC_FULL_VER

Take a look at the link. It's a reference for compiler specific pre processor defines.

Answer (score 4):

No, the way to get the name of the compiler is itself compiler-specific :-P.

gcc provides the `__VERSION__` macro, though.